# Javascript - Assign object item with values from another object

Tags: javascript

I have an object with few items and I want to update the values of one property `options` from another object.

Object 1 :

```
structure = [
        {
            id: 'name',
            label: 'Name',
            filterType: 'text',
            filterOn: 'contains'
        },
        {
            id: 'address',
            label: 'Address',
            filterType: 'text',
            filterOn: 'contains'
        },
        {
            id: 'phone',
            label: 'Phone',
            filterType: 'select',
            filterOn: 'contains',
            options: [{ label: 'abc', value: 'abc' },
                    { label: 'xyz', value: 'xyz' },
                    { label: 'mno', value: 'mno' }]
        }
    ];
```

if the id is phone then I want to get the values from the object 2 phoneList and assign it to the **options** instead of hard coding it.

```
  options: [{ label: 'abc', value: 'abc' },
                   { label: 'xyz', value: 'xyz' },
                   { label: 'mno', value: 'mno' }]
       }
   ];
```

object 2 is

```
this.props.phoneList = [{name: 'aaa', age: 11},{name : 'bbb' , age : 12}, and so on
```

]

label and values will be this.props.phoneList[i].name

how to loop over this and get the latest values from the other object

Comment: `if the id is phone then I want to get the values from the array and assign it to the options` what do you mean ? please share the result object you would like to get

Comment: the array `this.props.phoneList` has an object `name` with few values. I want to get the values from name and put it in the `options` object of label and value in the id = "phone"

Comment: how does the structure from ```this.props.phoneList``` look like? The same as the options object?

Comment: my bad - need to get the values from another object

Comment: @flappix - no the phoneList object is different . need to get the value of name and assign it to label and value in `options` object

Comment: const newArr = this.props.phoneList.map(phone => { here can access properties from phone })

Comment: @XXDebugger: And which of the elements in ```this.props.phoneList``` you want to assign to object1? All? Which one you mean by "latest value"?

Comment: I want to assign all the items from `this.props.phoneList` and create the `options` accordingly so If there are 5 items in the `phoneList` then 5 items in `options` should be created.

Answer (score 0):

First use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to identify the object with id `phone`. Then use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform `this.probs.phoneList` in the desired format and assign to `options`.

```
structure.filter (x => x.id == 'phone')[0].options = this.probs.phoneList.map (x => ({label: x.name, value: x.name}));
```